# Start different versions of Firefox from xfce4 main menu or panel item

Tags: xfce, firefox, menu

I'm using firefox version 61.0 on Centos 7 with xfce4. But I also need to use citrix reciever in firefox and this only works until firefox version 52. Therefor I have installed firefox version 52 with yum and I downloaded firefox version 61 into a different location. Now I can start firefox 61 or 52 from main menu or panel item. But when I try to start the other version while the first version is still running, firefox opens a new window with first version. I created a new profile called `old` in ~/.mozilla/firefox, started firefox 61 from panel item and startet firefox from terminal with `firefox -P old` and it works. I inserted this command into the firefox.desktop file but it does not work. Can someone explain, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I did wrong the first time. Maybe it was a simple typo or something similar. But I tried it again and created following ~/.local/share/applications/Firefox.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Firefox
Comment=Profile Old
Exec=firefox -P old
Icon=firefox
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
```

This works as expected. The old version of firefox is started with the old profile even if a new version of firefox is already started.